# Convert object to another

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a class which is part of an assembly i'm referencing.
I want to convert Object of that type
to my own class that implements the class i'm referencing

Lets say my reference has

```
public class customer
{
public string name {get;set}
public string address{get;set}
}
```

and i've created

```
public class mycustomer : customer
{
 public string name {get; set}
 public string address{get;set}
 public string email {get;set}
}
```

How do i convert customer to mycustomer and back
I've read about using reflections, but i'm not comfortable enough with it, to actually write it myself.

PS. please stop with the naming convention semantics - this is a rough on the fly theoretical example (not bothering with naming conventions here, only in actual code)
Thanks in advance

Edit: just figured out i cannot do this anyway.
i need to serialize an object with doesnt have the serializable attribute, and i thought i could just mirror that class and make it serializable - but i just realised that some of the properties inside this class doesn't have the serializable attribute.

so thanks anyway - i'll mark best answer to the question as answer
/Alex

Comment: Avoid needless inheritance.  Refactor customer and add the email property.  Use null or string.Empty to indicate the customer doesn't have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is there to help you out.

or if you have only class then it is fairly simple to write one of your own.

```
private mycustomer(customer c)
{
    return new mycustomer { name = c.Name, address = c.address,email = c.email };
}
```

You should not however that *you don't need inheritance to map*.

```
public class mycustomer : customer
```

should be

```
public class mycustomer
```

You should also use **this [naming convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx)**

```
public class MyCustomer
{
   public string Name {get; set}
   public string Address{get;set}
   public string Email {get;set}
}
```

Comment: naming conventions is really not the question here, since my example  is purely theoretical. 
I need to serialize Customer which doesn't have the serializable attribute ([serialize])
so i'm creating my "surrogate" class - which in turn does have the serializable attribute which is why I inherit to insure compatibility (please correct me if i'm assuming wrong here)

Comment: @AlekCarlsen pretty much every .net developer in the world use the same naming convention. This will be picked up on in every question you raise on SO tagged C#.

Comment: as do I.. but not in rough on the fly theoretical examples

Answer (score 3):

`mycustomer` already have members inherited from `customer`. Do not hide those members:

```
public class customer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class mycustomer : customer
{ 
    // name and address are inherited
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Now `mycustomer` IS A `customer`, and there is no problems with this conversion - just assign instance of `mycustomer` to variable of `customer` type:

```
mycustomer mc = new mycustomer();
customer c = mc;
```

Converting them back is strange, thus `customer` do not have `email` property and it will not appear - you still will have only data provided by base type, so simply use base type here. But if customer is actually a `mycustomer` instance (see code above) then all you need is casting:

```
mycustomer mc2 = (mycustomer)c;
```

BTW in C# we use PascalNaming for type names and public members.

Answer (score 3):

No need to write it yourself. You can copy a Customer's properties to a MyCustomer object using reflection with this generic algorithm:

```
    public B Convert<A, B>(A element) where B : A, new()
    {
        //get the interface's properties that implement both a getter and a setter
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(A)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToList();

        //create new object
        B b = new B();

        //copy the property values to the new object
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //read value
            object value = property.GetValue(element);

            //set value
            property.SetValue(b, value);
        }

        return b;
    }
```

I think using a full blown library like AutoMapper for just one scenario is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way!

```
public class ClassA
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }

 public class ClassB
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           //create an object with ClassA  type
            ClassA a = new ClassA { id=1,age=12,name="John",note="good"};
            ClassB b=a.Cast<ClassB>();
        }
```

"Cast" method implement follow this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUqfg9albdA